# How to redeem auth code and managing JWT in dotnetcore

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, identity

I have a react SPA - it calls a custom Identity Manager and if successful, responds with an auth code to the SPA app. e.g:

`https://my-identiymanager.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=******&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5001&scope=openid`

And it works, I get a code back in the redirect URL. Now, I would like to call my dotnetcore web api and use this code so that the server side webapi can fetch and maintain the JWTs for the browser session.

Is this a valid approach? I cannot find any example where the SPA app - on its own - fetches a code from a custom identity manager and then passes it to webapi so that the JWTs can be fetched and maintained securely on the server. Do I really have to build this entire JWT maintenance manually? That seems wrong - as though I'm not approaching this design correctly.

In my mind, if the webapi (server side) can securely redeem the code, store and maintain the JWTs after using the code - I would set a cookie on the client so that it could be identified on subsequent calls and use the correct JWTs when making requests.

Comment: I think the usual approach would be that the identity manager returns the jwt (or another token) in exchange for the code in the redirect url. The API can validate the jwt via the identity server, or (in case of jwt) because it had a valid signature

Comment: I can’t really see anything wrong with your approach though. Although I don’t understand your setup enough why you would do it the way you described

Comment: @NickyMuller - in my understanding, since the JWT is portable, it's more dangerous to have it on the client if you don't have to. The code is one-time, so let the server use it to request the JWT and keep them off the client (in this case browser) - I'm new to this though

Comment: And how does the server know your client is actually the authenticated client? Does it store a session cookie or something like that?

Comment: @NickyMuller - yes, exactly

Comment: Nevermind, you mentioned that in your question. A cookie set with the proper secure flags can be a bit more secure then storing the jwt in the browser local storage. Although, depending on the security requirement it wouldn’t add _that_ much, IMO

Comment: The main thing a cookie adds security wise is that it cannot be stolen easily via an XSS exploit, for example. Since it can’t easily be read via JS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to [azure ad auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#protocol-diagram) and it may help you to understand what azure did on this kind of authentication and authoration.

[image]

You wanna to set the auth code to the server then make the server generate access token, I think it go against the safety rules, though the auth code can be used only once. But let see, if someone can catch the auth code, why can't he catch your password and user account? That's why we create access token to access protected web apis. Because when access token be caught, only the specific apis are in the risk. And others don't know both other apis' url and their required scopes.

What azure ad did is let user signed in and get auth code from the redirected url. Then use the code with the scopes for specific api to generate an access token. This token can be decoded and we can see [the claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens) such as user id, scopes(for v2.0 token or resources for v1.0 token),expired time etc. And these claims are what the server needs to verify. Only the token with correct source scope can be used to access specific apis.

In frontend-backend-separated scheme, the backend or server need to filter the access token to judge it before it access the api, and the frontend like SPA written in react or some other framework, should integrate identity server and provide sign in module and generate access token for calling api.

And here's a [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/2-Authorization-I/1-call-graph) which used react integrate azure ad.